# Accessing data from column via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have a website which is running in Joomla 2.5 with MyBlog. I am creating a external application which takes data from MyBlog tables and displays to website users.

In MyBlog comment tables, there is a column name 'comment_author_data'. In this column the data inside looks something like this:
{"name":"xxxxx","email":"xxxx@gmail.com","id":"xxx"}

I want to access the value from the name and Email Id and Id from the data.

How do I access them using PHP ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried something yet?

Comment: look at how to import the Joomla framework externally and how to write a query to get data from a Joomla database table. There are more than enough docs for this. If you encounter a specific problem with your code and provide examples of what you've tried, you will more likely get an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a json string. you can access the values of name and email by using `json_decode()`.

```
<?php 

$string = ' {"name":"xxxxx","email":"xxxx@gmail.com","id":"xxx"}';

$data = json_decode($string);

print_r($data);

?>
```

returns

```
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => xxxxx
    [email] => xxxx@gmail.com
    [id] => xxx
)
```

which allows you to access it like so:

`print $data->name;`

Comment: Hi dbh, thank for your solution.... it really worked for me.... really appreciated the quick reply...

Comment: @mkb no worries mate, glad this helped you and solved your issue!